# Why does this example from Haskell's SVGFonts library fail to compile?

Tags: haskell

Using Haskell's `SVGFonts` library, I am trying to use the `textSVG_` function to generate a diagram. Here is the example I am trying to follow, which is included in the code by the [definition of `textSVG_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/SVGFonts-1.7.0.1/docs/Graphics-SVGFonts.html#v:textSVG_):

```
text'' t = (textSVG_ (TextOpts lin INSIDE_H KERN True 1 1) t)
           # fc blue # lc blue # bg lightgrey # fillRule EvenOdd # showOrigin
```

It uses `lin` in `TextOpts`' `textFont` field. However, there appears to be a type mismatch between what is expected by `TextOpts`' `textFont` field, and the definition of `lin`.
[`TextOpts`' definition](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/SVGFonts-1.7.0.1/docs/Graphics-SVGFonts.html#t:TextOpts) shows the `textFont` field to have type `textFont :: PreparedFont n`, whereas the [definition of `lin`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/SVGFonts-1.7.0.1/docs/Graphics-SVGFonts.html#v:lin) shows it to have type `lin :: (Read n, RealFloat n) => IO (PreparedFont n)`.

Why the `IO` in `lin`? It throws a type mismatch when I attempt to compile it.

```
Couldn't match type `IO
                         (Graphics.SVGFonts.ReadFont.PreparedFont Double)'
                 with `(Graphics.SVGFonts.ReadFont.FontData n,
                        Graphics.SVGFonts.ReadFont.OutlineMap n)'
  Expected type: Graphics.SVGFonts.ReadFont.PreparedFont n
    Actual type: IO (Graphics.SVGFonts.ReadFont.PreparedFont Double)
```

How can I simply provide a `PreparedFont n` to `TextOpts`'s `textFont` field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that their documentation is outdated and no longer matches their code, as of commit [`61424cc`](https://github.com/diagrams/SVGFonts/commit/61424cca2bb752d756f9bec641e28ecd106a297c). (This is why you should use doctests, people!)

You can't use `lin` while it's still wrapped in `IO`. Do something like this instead:

```
do
  lin' <- lin
  let text'' t = (textSVG_ (TextOpts lin' INSIDE_H KERN True 1 1) t)
                 # fc blue # lc blue # bg lightgrey # fillRule EvenOdd # showOrigin
```

If you don't have `IO` handy there, then make it a function argument and get the font later:

```
text'' font t = (textSVG_ (TextOpts font INSIDE_H KERN True 1 1) t)
                # fc blue # lc blue # bg lightgrey # fillRule EvenOdd # showOrigin
```

Or you can cheat, [like they do in their `Default` instance](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/SVGFonts-1.7.0.1/docs/src/Graphics.SVGFonts.Text.html#line-41):

```
text'' t = (textSVG_ (TextOpts (unsafePerformIO lin) INSIDE_H KERN True 1 1) t)
           # fc blue # lc blue # bg lightgrey # fillRule EvenOdd # showOrigin
```